# How to write to a Windows formatted disk from OS X?

Tags: macos, external-disk, disk-format, ntfs

I have 4 external hard disk formatted on Windows as NTFS, but they are lying unused since I bought a Mac. So I am looking forward somehow I should be able to write to those disc without having to format them! Is there anyway I can do that?

I also tried NTFS-3G but it is giving me this error!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### [Paragon NTFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) or [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/)

Paragon NTFS and Tuxera NTFS will let you read/write NTFS partitions on OS X. They integrate with Disk Utility as well, letting you erase and partition such disks.

Comment: "Tuxera NTFS for Mac" should also work with OS X Mavericks: http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/